# Does SessionImplementor have access to a TransactionManager in Hibernate 5.x?

Tags: java, hibernate

In Hibernate 3.x you were able to access a TransactionManager like:

```
sessionImplementor.getFactory().getTransactionManager();
```

I was wondering if you could do something similar with SessionImplementor in hibernate 5? Is there still a way to access TransactionManage?

Answer (score -1):

Hibernate 5 migration, please refer the below URL,https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.0/migration-guide.adoc#transactions

Comment: I've check the migration guide but it didnt say anything about getting the TransactionManager Object

Comment: Don't know what exactly trying to do? if you are looking for isolated then check below one,https://itdevworld.wordpress.com/2010/06/27/hibernate-isolater-doisolatedwork-websphere-compliant-implementation-based-on-uowmanager-rununderuow/